# Best way to net values in successive rows of CSV

Tags: javascript, python, excel, csv, data-munging

Looking for advice on the best way to perform the following operation.  Preferably in python, javascript, or excel.  Data is in CSV (although I removed the commas below).  I'm a noob; I should be able to do it, but I'm thinking there's an elegant way to do something like this since it is such a basic operation.

```
Direction    Name       Trial    Amount
        +    Matthew        1       500
        -    Matthew        1       250
        -    Matthew        1       250
        +    Matthew        2      1000
        -    Matthew        2       750
        +    Matthew        3       500
        +    Mark           1       500
        -    Mark           1       250
        +    Luke           1      1000
        +    Luke           2      1000
        +    Luke           3      1000
        -    Luke           2       500
```

**Net each amount by name and trial (large number of trials in dataset).**

Result would be:

```
Direction    Name       Trial    Amount
        +    Matthew        2       250
        +    Matthew        3       500
        +    Mark           1       250
        +    Luke           1      1000
        +    Luke           2       500
        +    Luke           3      1000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show us what you've attempted to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['vals'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Amount'] if x['Direction'] == '+' else x['Amount']*-1, axis=1)

pd.pivot_table(df, values='vals', columns=['Name','Trial'], aggfunc=np.sum)

Name     Trial
Luke     1        1000
         2         500
         3        1000
Mark     1         250
Matthew  1           0
         2         250
         3         500
dtype: int64
```